# Using Doctrine takes up to 250ms only for connection

Tags: php, database, doctrine

Hello i using Doctrine with APC caching - only if the DB connect the response of a website increases up of 250ms. Is there a solution with a DB connect that not increases the page load time?

Comment: ORM or ODM? (doctrine)

Comment: I use doctrine ORM with mysql